# Quarkus HTTPS restful service

Tags: java, quarkus

Is there any example/tutorial to build and configure TLS-secured restful service using quarkus.io?

Unfortunately I can not find one neither at quarkus documentation, no here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is indeed supported by our Undertow extension but, unfortunately, not documented.

You can define things like the following:

```
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.file=...
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-file=...
...
```

in your application.properties.

The config entry point is `ServerSslConfig` (see https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/core/runtime/src/main/java/io/quarkus/runtime/configuration/ssl/ServerSslConfig.java#L41). You then add the nested properties with dots and transform camel-case to dashes.

If you want to build a native executable, there's a good chance you will have to add `quarkus.ssl.native=true` too.

If you have feedback or if you want to contribute a guide for that, feel free to join us on Zulip or open issues/PRs on GitHub.

Comment: I just opened https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/1947 to track further progress on this.

Comment: Fine! Thanks for you reply, I will try that.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. But you have hardcoded password for keystore at ServerSslConfig.java:158.

Comment: Would you be interested to share your findings here: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json-guide . A paragraph about how to set up an SSL service would be nice. As for the hardcoded password, I noticed that. Please open a GitHub issue.

Comment: Issue is opened: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2021 Please tell me how to share my findings?

Comment: I think I would add a specific paragraph here just before the conclusion: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/rest-json-guide.adoc . For now it's probably the best place. It's asciidoc, you have plenty of example of how to format it in the file. Feel free to open a PR and ask for advice once you have a draft, I'm here to help!

Comment: I just posted short guide here as an answer. Please feel free to copy it anywhere you need.

Answer (score 15):

Thanks mr. Guillaume Smet, I found the solution. Here is "from zero to hello in 5 minutes with Quarkus and SSL guide". This is done by quarkus undertow plugin. Also you will need text editor, jdk 1.8+ and maven installed.

Frist, create the project.

```
mkdir restls
cd restls
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:create -DprojectGroupId=org.acme -DprojectArtifactId=restls -DclassName="org.acme.HelloResource" -Dpath="/hello" -Dextensions="undertow"
```

Open your application config file `src/main/resources/application.properties` with any editor and add lines:

```
quarkus.http.port=80
quarkus.http.ssl-port=443
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=keystore.jks
```

Create keystore containing self-signed certificate (answer all questions and specify password namelly "password"):

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 365 -keysize 2048
```

The file `keystore.jks` must be in the `src/main/resources/` folder.

Build the project:

```
mvnw clean package quarkus:build
```

Now try it out:

```
java -jar target/restls-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

Navigate to https://localhost/hello and allow your browser to trust certificate. That's all.

You can override options in invocation time like this:

```
java -Dquarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file=/path-to-keystore/keystore-name.jks -jar target/restls-1.0-SNAPSHOT-runner.jar
```

Finally, here is the concerning options list:

```
quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.file -- The file path to a server certificate or certificate chain in PEM format.

quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-file -- The file path to the corresponding certificate private key file in PEM format.

quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file -- An optional key store which holds the certificate information instead of specifying separate files.

quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-store-file-type -- An optional parameter to specify type of the key store file. If not given, the type is automatically detected based on the file name.
```

You can specifiy either certificate + key files in PEM format or keystore.

Comment: Thanks for this. With Quarkus 0.18.0, I had to specify the cert + key files. For some reason, the cert was not being served when keystore was used causing handshake failures.

Comment: Just a heads-up, the password to the keystore on the "-storepass" keytool parameter *must* be "password", I thought it was just an example but apparently the string "password" is indeed hardcoded as the password to the keystore as said in the comments to Mr @guillaume-smet answer.

Answer (score -1):

adding some notes here for how you would use native quarkus tls (reverse_proxy for example)  as things constantly evolve

1. for extensions defined here [tls enabled extensions](https://quarkus.io/guides/native-and-ssl)
2. generate a CA with SAN for the hostname
3. using your CA create a openssl x509 and key PEM format
4. in application.properties define eg hostname =  quarkus-dev
   `quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.file=quarkus-dev.pem`
   `quarkus.http.ssl.certificate.key-file=quarkus-dev-key.pem`
   `quarkus.ssl.native=true`
5. with this set up the quarkus binary will look for the x509 cert and key in the same directory
   [image]

Notes
some open ssl fragments for generation of the certs

CA key
`openssl genrsa -out quarkus-dev-key.pem 2048`

CA extension shows SAN dns entry

```
authorityKeyIdentifier=keyid,issuer
basicConstraints=CA:FALSE
keyUsage = digitalSignature, nonRepudiation, keyEncipherment, dataEncipherment
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = quarkus-dev
```

generate the CA

```
openssl req -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout quarkus-dev-key.pem -out quarkus-dev.csr -subj "/C=CA/ST=QUARKUS/L=QUARKUS/O=QUARKUS/OU=QUARKUS/CN=quarkus-dev" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:quarkus-dev" 

openssl x509 -req -in quarkus-dev.csr -CA quarkus-dev-ca.crt -CAkey quarkus-dev-ca.key -CAcreateserial -out quarkus-dev.pem -outform PEM -days 825 -sha256 -passin file:quarkus-dev-ca.pass -extfile quarkus-dev.ext
```

with the CA above you can generate the certificates
if using the SAN dns then you would need to update /etc/hosts or alternatively you could use the IP in the SAN like

```
[alt_names]
IP.1 = 192.168.0.1
```