# Redirect to https in Quarkus

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, quarkus

What is the easiest way to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS in Quarkus?

I've searched the config documentation https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config but couldn't find anything.

I tried to add the undertow dependency and a web.xml to force a https connection. The web.xml I added looks like this:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
</web-app>`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to add the undertow dependency and a web.xml to force a https connection. Also I tried to find configuration parameters like `http.disable` or `https.only`.

Comment: That's best done by your app server, not your code.

Answer (score 0):

First how to create certificate and give to quarkus. you can see details about in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55647430/175554).

[The problem](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/9371) is `mvn quarkus:dev` does not work with SSL. I got `Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: .\keystore.jks` but good news normal java -jar runs correctly.
[image: how to run java jar]

[Here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/blob/master/local-ssl-usage/src/main/resources/application.properties) is the configuration you are looking for more precisely `quarkus.http.insecure-requests=redirect` it does not work without providing a certificate. You can see how did I create the certificate [here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/blob/master/local-ssl-usage/README.md)

Screen capture to show how it works in firefox, check the bottom dev console. 
[image: How looks oon firefox]

And last but not least here is a running example https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/quarkus-examples/tree/master/local-ssl-usage